# Como posso executar meu script tendo a certeza que foi executado como administrado?

Tags: windows, batch

Quero executar um batch(.bat) e verificar se ele foi aberto como administrador, aqui há um exemplo do que eu quero no linux:

```
if [ `whoami` == 'root' ] then
    echo I am root
else
    echo I am not root
fi
```

Pesquisei mas só encontrei estes métodos:

1 - Não quero usar destas forma porque o usuário administrador pode usar outro nome.

```
runas /user:Administrator meubat.bat
```

2 - Verificando o retorno deste comando eu não posso pegar nada que me possa ter certeza que estou como administrador

```
whoami /priv
```

Executando o comando (whoami /priv):

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Executando o comando(whoami /priv) como administrador:

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Este comando mostra o mesmo nome de usuário executando como administrado ou não.

```
echo %USERDOMAIN%\%USERNAME%
```

Como posso executar meu script tendo a certeza que foi executado como administrado?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Essa atualmente é a melhor forma:

```
@echo off
echo Detectando privilegios...
net session >nul 2>&1
if %errorLevel% == 0 (
    rem //Comandos com privilegios de Administrador
    echo Privilegios de Administrador confirmados.
) else (
    rem //Comandos sem privilegios de Administrador
    echo Sem privilegios de Administrador.
)

pause >nul
```

Funciona com:

- Windows XP
- Windows Vista
- Windows 7
- Windows 8
- Windows 10